# Nginx, authentication working, but once authenticated it downloads the page rather than displaying it?

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

I have configured a bit of basic authentication to prevent access to a directory called camera, this is the code in my sites-enabled directory on the nginx server :

```
location ^~ /camera/ {
auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
auth_basic_user_file  conf.d/htpasswd;
}
```

the authentication is working, where it will not proceed if the username /password is wrong, however what is happening now, instead of showing the user the restricted pages, it downloads the php files instead, obviously this is not what i want, how can i stop this and show the page instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read how is locations work: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location
After match `/camera/` location nginx stop to search any other locations.

> If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.

You need to add nested location inside `/camera/` for process .php files.
For example:

```
 location ^~ /camera/ {
    auth_basic "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file  conf.d/htpasswd;
    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass ...;
    }
 }
```